# C++ destructors question

Tags: c++, destructor

With regards to the sample code below, why is the destructor for the base class called twice?

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() {
        std::cout << "Base::Base()" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Base() {
        std::cout << "Base::~Base()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {
        std::cout << "Derived::Derived()" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Derived() {
        std::cout << "Derived::~Derived()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Base a = Derived();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is a sample of the output when the program is run:

```
Base::Base()
Derived::Derived()
Derived::~Derived()
Base::~Base()
Base::~Base()
```

Comment: Fixed the formatting of your code. First time I've seen So screw up the formatting that badly. ;)

Comment: To see what is going on more add a copy constructor for Base. Then you will see the missing construction associated with the mismatched destructors.

Comment: Yeah, good piece of advice. When testing stuff like this, always make sure *all* constructors (plus the assignment operator) are tracked. Otherwise you may miss half the stuff that's going on.

Comment: And even Base const&a = Derived(); would not require a virtual destructor for ~Derived to be called, and no slicing taking place then: http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What happens is called slicing. You initialize an object of type `Base` with an object of type `Derived`. Since any object of type `Derived` has also an object of type `Base` contained (called "base-class sub-object"), there will be two `Base` objects and one `Derived` object in existance throughout the program. The Derived object (and its base-class sub-object of type `Base`) only exists for the time of initialization, while the remaining `Base` object exists until end of `main`.

Since there are two Base objects and one Derived object, you will also see one more Base destructors run.

Comment: Doh, the slicing hadn't occurred to me at all, just the nonvirtual destructor. Nice catch.

Comment: Exactly.  The compiler synthesised copy constructor is applied to init the Base object with a Derived object and of course object slicing is taking place also.

Answer (score 7):

A copy constructor is being used. If you want to see what is going on, instrument the copy constructor too:

```
 Base( const Base & ) {
        std::cout << "Base::Base( const Base &)" << std::endl;
    }
```

and similarly for Derived.

Note that this has NOTHING to do with the destructors not being virtual.

Comment: Furthermore, output the this pointer as well, to demonstrate that there are two objects (and object slicing).

Comment: Neil, that is it.  A copy constructor is being synthesised b the compiler and used to init the base object, When the Base object is going out of scope, the destructor is called twice.

Comment: Object slicing is also taking place, as the Base copy constructor is taking a Derived object.

Answer (score 4):

When you say `Derived()` in `main()` it creates a temporary object which is then copied into object a. Hence there are two objects because of which destructor is called twice. Also, as others pointed out your base class destructor should be virtual.

Answer (score 2):

Because you create a temporary of type `Derived` before copy-constructing `a` with it. So this is basically what happens:

```
Derived d(); // Your temporary of type Derived is created
Base a(d); // The temporary is used to call a's copy constructor 
d.Derived::~Derived(); // The temporary is destroyed, calling both ~Derived and ~Base
a.Base::~Base(); // The nonvirtual destructor on a is called, so ~Base is called, but not ~Derived
```

So apart from the unnecessary copying at the beginning (which the compiler may optimize away), the actual *error* is that ~Base isn't virtual.

**Edit**
Oops, completely missed the slicing that takes place as litb pointed out. Read his answer instead :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding in the following will make the program more clear:

```
 Base(const Base& base){
        std::cout << "Base::Base(const Base& base)" << std::endl;
 }
```

The compiler will automatically create a copy constructor for you.  By defining it yourself, (and by adding in the print) you can see that the number of constructors and destructors match

```
Base::Base()
Derived::Derived()
Base::Base(const Base& base)
Derived::~Derived()
Base::~Base()
Base::~Base()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a [virtual destructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#C.2B.2B).

Comment: Wrong. this has nothing to do with the bhaviour the questioner is seeing. a virtuial destructor is only required if you delete an object of a Derived class via a Base pointer, whuich is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

You have one stack variable and one temporary - total of two objects constructed - so it's logical for the destructor to be called twice.

Answer (score 0):

1) A temporary object of Derived type is built (Derived::Derived() and Base::Base() are called)

2) The temp object is copied into "a"

3) The temporary object is destroyed ( Derived::~Derived() and Base::~Base() are called)

4) return EXIT_SUCCESS;

5) "a" is destroyed, so Base::~Base() is called